# Escaping double quotes while executing powershell commands from batch file

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, command, escaping

I have to use replace command with regex in the PowerShell command. Replace with RegEx works only with double quotes ("). Also to execute the PowerShell command in batch file, the command must be inside double quotes (") like this:

```
powershell -command ""
```

So, is there a way to escape the double quotes used with the replace command as the below is throwing error because of conflict in double quotes:

```
powershell -command "$content -replace ",$", ",NULL""
```

I have tried using (`) like:

```
powershell -command "$content -replace `",$`", `",NULL`""
```

Could anyone please suggest some solution?

Comment: Replace with regex **doesn't** work only with doublequotes. Did you try `-replace ',$', ',NULL'`?

Comment: You could of course try to escape the internal doublequotes using backslashes too, `-replace \",$\", \",NULL\"`.

Answer (score 1):

Use twice the double quote symbol (i.e. "") to escape it in PowerShell.

`echo "Here is my ""double quoted"" test."`

This will print: Here is my "double quoted" test.

Did you try something like:

```
-command "$content -replace "",$"", "",NULL"""
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a late response,
But you can use `'` quotes between the double quotes, you can then write this:
`powershell -command "$content -replace ',$', ',NULL'"`